# Zend ErrorController view problems

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, controller

I'm having problems with the view for my error controller view in a ZF application. I am using a default layout, and just adding an error message to it. However, my images don't always show up in the view for 404 errors.

If I type a non-existent controller like : mysite.com/contactasddf, it shows the images fine
If I type a legit controller, but non-existent action like: mysite.com/contact/asdf, the images don't show up

Thoughts?

Comment: I dont quite get the question... can you phrase it a little more directly -> or show a code example ?

Answer (score 0):

How are you referencing the images?

In HTML, use the [BaseUrl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) helper, eg

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/foo.jpg') ?>">
```

Same goes for referencing stylesheets, just use relative paths from the stylesheet location within the CSS, eg

```
background-image: url(../images/foo.jpg);
```